# How Can I Extract Specific Text From External Webpage?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, html-content-extraction

I spent hours searching and trying without much success...

I want to know how can I extract specific data from external webpage, for example:

Page - `www.example.com/A/B/C`
Within the page:

```
<td class="classA">Text1</td> 
<td><b class="classB">text2</b> other text... </td>
```

classA and classB appears only there, and I want to the data: **Text1 + Text2**

If you can help me with this (in JavaScript) I will be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions.  See string.match() method.

Comment: Regular expressions or getElementBy are the second part i think, first i need to retrieve the external web page..